# Issues with Wake on LAN using Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: wakeonlan

I have two machines, both running Ubuntu 18.04. My objective to to have WOL working on both machines.

On one machine (PC1) I have WOL working perfectly, however I cannot get WOL working on the other machine (PC2).

My Set up (on both PCs) is:

I have disabled Network Manager as follows:

```
sudo systemctl stop NetworkManager
sudo systemctl disable NetworkManager
sudo systemctl mask NetworkManager
```

I have enabled networkd as follows:

```
sudo systemctl unmask systemd-networkd.service
sudo systemctl enable systemd-networkd.service
sudo systemctl start systemd-networkd.service
```

I have modified the only file in directory */etc/netplan*, namely */etc/netplan/01-network-manager-all.yaml* so it looks like this (PC1):

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eno1:
      addresses:
        - 192.168.1.113/24
      gateway4: 192.168.1.1
      wakeonlan: true
      nameservers:
        addresses: [103.86.96.100, 103.86.99.100]
```

PC2 is exactly the same except *eno1* is *enp1s0* and the IP address is different (of course).

Both machines boot up fine, the ethernet connection is OK, I can access internet OK from both machines.

If I type

```
sudo ethtool enp1s0
```

on PC2 I get this (extract):

```
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: d
```

on PC1 (eno1) I get (extract)

```
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
```

If I type (on PC2):

```
sudo ethtool -s enp1s0 wol g
```

and then

```
sudo ethtool enp1s0
```

I get

```
Supports Wake-on: pumbg
Wake-on: g
```

If I then switch off PC2, WOL works as expected (but this, of course, is only 'one-time').

If I put the line *sudo ethtool -s enp1s0 wol g* in a **startup** script or a **shutdown** script that I have on PC2 (both run with sudo permissions) then WOL doesn't work.

The only difference I perceive between PC1 and PC2 is the motherboard; PC2 has a Gigabyte GA-H110M-S2H; PC1 has an ASUS SABERTOOTH X79)

I would be most grateful for any suggestions or insights anyone may have.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wouldn't wake on lan be more down to settings you have in BIOS rather than Ubuntu it self ? Which would explain the difference between two motherboards being a factor.

Comment: @Oskar-l thanks for you fast reply. Both the BIOS and *Ubuntu System* need to be configured. The *wakeonlan: true* in the  yaml file should do the *Ubuntu System" part. I know the BIOS part is working because everything works as expected when I type *sudo ethtool -s enp1s0 wol g * on the CLI.

Answer (score 0):

Fixed.

This turns out to be a driver issue. The NIC on the Gigabyte GA-H110M-S2H is a Realtek 8168 device; Ubuntu was using a 8169 driver. To fix this I did the following:

```
sudo apt-get install r8168-dkms
```

The procedure took a little while because the new driver is built and installed to  my Kernel. (The dkms ensures that that if any Kernel update happens then the new Kernel will be re-built automatically).

I had to reboot for WOL to work.